# Ignore failure when existing strings in the error message

Tags: ansible, try-catch

How to ignore a failure when there are some specific strings inside the error message?

***stdout_lines :***

```
failed: [lab_ansible] => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "cmd-agent stop lz", "delta": "0:00:02.398303", "end": "2020-07-14 13:17:04.858006", "failed_when_result": true, "item": "lz", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2020-07-14 13:17:02.459703", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Processing. Please wait...\nStopping Monitoring Agent for Linux OS ...\nAgent is not running...", "stdout_lines": ["Processing. Please wait...", "Stopping Monitoring Agent for Linux OS ...", "Agent is not running..."]}
```

***Tentative:***

```
- name: "Stopping agent"
  shell: cmd-agent stop lz
  register: stopped_lz
  failed_when: ( stopped_lz.stdout_lines not in ['Agent is not running...', 'Agent stopped...'] )
```

As mentioned above, the playbook is still closed due to failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per the requirement, you are checking whether agent is stopped or not. If agent is still running then it should fail the playbook execution otherwise it must pass. I believe that below sample script will be able to help you fulfil your requirement.

```
---
- hosts: all
  name: "[ Playbook Example ]"
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
       - failure_message: "Agent is not running"
  tasks:
          - name: "[ Verify Failure Message ]"
            command: "echo The failure message is {{ failure_message }}"
            register: failure_reg
            failed_when:
               - "'Agent is not running' not in failure_reg.stdout"
               - "'Agent stopped' not in failure_reg.stdout"

          - debug:
                  msg: "{{ failure_reg.stdout }}"
```